# In the Epic card game, when is event damage resolved during the attack?

Tags: epic-card-game

In the Epic card game I understand that damage taken and received as part of an attack is resolved simultaneously at the end of the battle.

However, if I attack with two creatures and both receive enough damage via events to kill (break) them, before the defender selects blockers, are the creatures killed instantly, or do they still need to decide whether to defend or take the damage from the attack?

Comment: If someone could with sufficient rights could add a new tag for the Epic card game and remove `reference` that would be great. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Complete Rules](http://www.epiccardgame.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/EpicCompleteRules-1.pdf):

> 5.16.3 If a champion has taken damage equal to or exceeding its defense in a single turn, **it is immediately broken**.

Thus the defending player will take no damage from the attack. It looks like technically there is still a "Choose Blockers" step even if all attackers are dead, but you can just block with nothing. (Description of Battle Phase: [Rulebook](http://downloads.starrealms.com/Epic-Card-Game-Rule-Book-v2.pdf) p12, or Complete Rules 4.4)